# nested ng-repeat for object within an object within an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

I want to achieve the above image using angular-js ng-repeat. i got a problem for the third column.

```
<div tasty-table
     bind-resource-callback="showTCS.loadAllTCS"
     bind-init="showTCS.init"
     bind-filters="showTCS.listParams"
     bind-reload="showTCS.reloadCallback">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-overflow"
           cellpadding="4"
           cellspacing="4"
           align="center">
        <thead tasty-thead bind-not-sort-by="showMainCategory.notSortBy"></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="tcs in rows">
                <td>{{tcs.trackName}}</td>
                <td>
                    <table align="left">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="category in tcs.category">
                                <td>{{category.categoryName}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <table> //this one should be on the 3rd <td> of parent table
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="skill in category.skill">
                                                <td>{{skill.skillName}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a ui-sref="mainCategoryDetails( {mainCatId: mainCategory.mainCat_id} )" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ng-if="(!rows.length)" colspan="4" class="text-center">No results found.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div tasty-pagination bind-items-per-page="showTCS.itemsPerPage" bind-list-items-per-page="showTCS.listItemsPerPage"></div>
</div>
```

This is what i have tried so far and the output is not what i want as shown in the sample image. The problem is how to output the last data which is skills in the third  of the parent table.

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai already posted my code

Comment: You can find your answer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18409175/5958860

Comment: @SecretCoding, please post your json also.

Comment: @MaoStream the link you gave shows unordered list which is not the same from my problem. unordered list is much simplier to handle compared to table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer, not quite good since it keeps repeating the tbody but its still ok

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="padding-top: 2%">
<div tasty-table
     bind-resource-callback="showTCS.loadAllTCS"
     bind-init="showTCS.init"
     bind-filters="showTCS.listParams"
     bind-reload="showTCS.reloadCallback">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-overflow"
           cellpadding="4"
           cellspacing="4"
           align="center">
        <thead tasty-thead bind-not-sort-by="showTCS.notSortBy"></thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="tcs in rows">
            <tr ng-repeat="category in tcs.category">
                <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align:middle;">{{tcs.trackName}}</td>
                <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align:middle;">{{category.categoryName}}</td>
                <td>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled" >
                        <li ng-repeat="skill in category.skill">{{skill.skillName}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a ui-sref="mainCategoryDetails( {mainCatId: mainCategory.mainCat_id} )" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></a>
                    <a ui-sref="editMainCategory( {mainCatId: mainCategory.mainCat_id} )" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
                    <a ui-sref="deleteMainCategory( {mainCatId:  mainCategory.mainCat_id} )" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ng-if="(!rows.length)" colspan="4" class="text-center">No results found.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div tasty-pagination bind-items-per-page="showTCS.itemsPerPage" bind-list-items-per-page="showTCS.listItemsPerPage"></div>
</div>
```